# Specman list pseudo-method to pop/push from/to specific index

Tags: specman

I am looking for a way to implement a new List pseud-method that would
push/pop from a certain location in the list (not necessarily from index 0).

is there a way to add list pseudo-methods?

Answer (score 2):

Implementing list pseudo-methods can be dont using macros.
Here is an example fpr how to implement the desired pop from index pseudo method:

```
define <my_n_pop'exp> "<list'exp>[ ].[ ]pop_index[ ]\(<num'exp>\)" as {


evaluate typeof_item(<list'exp>) {
    if(<list'exp>.size()> <num'exp>) {
        value = <list'exp>[<num'exp>];
        <list'exp>.delete(<num'exp>);
    }else {
        error("error : This list is has the size of ",<list'exp>.size(),"and you requested item",<num'exp>);
    };
  };
 };
```

The usage from within the code will look something like this:

```
 i=l.pop_index(2); // pop the item with index 2. All greater indices will decrease by 1.
```

Comment: Actually, with this macro you do get a good error message if you try to use it with something which is not a list. It says something like "Expression 'i' is not a list" and points both into the macro and to the source line where the macro is used.